# Get multiple patches by patch-ahead NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

`patch-ahead distance` reports the single patch ahead.

How do I get a set of patches within a radius of that ahead point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a reporter to do this for you, something like:

```
to-report patches-ahead [ rad dis ] ; turtle reporter
  report [patches in-radius rad] of patch-ahead dis
end
```

Just note that it has to be called by a turtle- for example:

```
to setup
  ca
  crt 1
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask patches [ 
    set pcolor black
  ]
  ask turtles [
    rt random 61 - 30
    fd 1
    ask patches-ahead 3 7 [ 
      set pcolor white
    ]
  ]
  tick
end
```